# Bash shell doesn't show Python unittest output, reset doesn't fix the shell either

Tags: python, bash, shell, vim, tmux

OS: Fedora 23

I started using vim + tmux for my programming and suddenly after accidentally smashing couple of keys [Forgive me I am a klutz] the bash shell started acting weirdly.

When I run my unittest written in Python they don't seem to have run, since there is no output on the shell. However if I press 'ENTER' twice the output shows up just fine.

I tried using the `reset` command and it didn't change this behaviour. I've looked at several threads [linked below] that seem to share my problem, however for the other guys the problem was for every output not just Python and it seemed to have fixed itself when they ran `reset`.

I've tried restarting my computer along with the `reset` command which didn't change anything.

The other thread requested someone to post their stty `-a` output, so I'll add that here:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 39; columns 103; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>;
start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -extproc
```

Thread I was referring to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/171449/shell-does-not-show-typed-in-commands-reset-works-but-what-happened

Comment: First thing to do after screwing up your terminal: `stty sane`. Can't believe it's not mentioned in the other thread.

Comment: OK I ran that command but didn't fix the problem or seem to change anything in particular.

Comment: start another terminal? Good luck.

Comment: Does this persist across terminal instances? Because `reset` and `stty sane` should reset just about everything possible to get you back to usable. If this persists into new terminal instances though then that is the wrong level to be looking at.

Comment: @EtanReisner if by different 'instances' you mean new window, then yes the problem persists. Restarting the computer or the shell has no effect.

Comment: What terminal are you using? Does using a different terminal show the same behavior? (e.g. xterm, rxvt, rxvt-unicode/urxvt, konsole, gnome-terminal, etc.)

Comment: @EtanReisner  I am using gnome-terminal 3.18.2. Also thanks a lot for all the responses :D

Comment: Yes, does using a different terminal show the same issue? (i.e. Is this a shell or terminal issue?)

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes the problem persists when I use xterm